# Content Pushed off screen using Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css

So I'm simply trying to do some content in a paragraph next to an image. I have a container that encompasses both of them, such that:

```
container {
    position: relative:
    width: 900px;
}
```

Withing the container I have content and an image, so:

```
#container p {
    float: left;
}

#container img {
    float: right;
}
```

I've read that I should try positioning the img absolutely, and the p relatively, along with the container being relatively positioned as well. No matter what combination of things I try, the text either goes across the screen and you see a tiny bit of the image as it sits on the right side of the container, or the text rolls over the image totally, or the image sits on top and all the text gets pushed down to the bottom.

Anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try floating the img and not the p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you just want text to wrap around an image you should just need a float on the image and not the paragraph

```
float: right/left;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/fEfu2/

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
  width: 900px;
}

#container p {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}

#container img {
  max-width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
```

Tweak accordingly, I guess. Usually you just float the graphic and let the text flow around it. You should consider doing some basic tutorials in CSS. It seems like some of these ideas you've tried are not good ways to do it.